# controller/service/repository style, should service wrap repository for other service

Tags: design-patterns

My project followed a controller/service/repository style, like
`UserController -> UserService -> UserRepository` and `ShopController -> ShopService -> ShopRepository`. Now I want to fetch user from ShopService, should I call UserService or call UserRepository directly from ShopService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding Repository should only be accessed from Service layers.

Expose well known interfaces via service layer. Any changes to repository (like underlying ORM change or DB change) will go unknown to consumer client.

So to answer your question -  call `UserService`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I still use repository to avoid cycle dependencies, thank you.